# Organizing content using tabs and sidebar

Tags: website-design, mobile, dashboard, organization

In my customers dashboard (web), they can select products and see their respective stats, edit them... This is organized like this on PC:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foybjw.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**First I'm not sure this organisation is the best, and secondly, how to organize that in a mobile site?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you have both view tabs and edit tabs in the same hierarchy. To most people, tabs organize viewed data into logical sections, not separate different tasks (such as edit meta, description, and images). So your Overview, Stats, and Mods can stay as they are, but the rest of them should be transferred to the Overview pane as buttons or items in a popup menu. "Edit" is an action, so buttons or menu items are a better candidates for it than tab.

On a mobile site, you would list the products on the page. Tapping on one would immediately refresh the whole screen and load the overview page. Then you would have buttons or popup menus on the overview page to get to the rest of the data/tasks. Now, since you can only see one of those panes at a time, make sure that your heading indicates which product you're working on.